# Does mutex guarded scope guarantee that threads read and write in the actual global variable and not their thread context alone?

Tags: multithreading, global-variables, mutex, shared-memory

As I understand, threads have their own copy of global variables in their thread contexts. Now, will the mere mentioning (writing/reading) of a global variable within the scope of a mutex guard or within a critical section guarantee that the reading or writing of that global variable becomes universal, and not local to the thread's context?

In other words, all access to the variable by all threads will happen with the same mutex lock follow by unlock, both reading and writing.

Comment: A mutex guarantees mutual exclusion and ordering of memory operations. When mutex guarded block terminates, memory operations in the block is guaranteed to be visible. Within the block, there are usually no guarantees. This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier

Comment: @BurakSerdar Then how to guarantee that a global variable's value is universal and not a local thread context copy? Does using the same mutex on all threads for accessing the same global variable guarantee an always-universally-true variable value?

Comment: Here's typically what the guarantee is: if a writer thread does lock-write vars-unlock and all reader threads do lock-read vars-unlock, then all readers are guaranteed to see the  the vars either before the lock of the writer, or after the unlock of writer.

Comment: If a reader reads vars without locking, usually nothing is guaranteed.

Comment: @BurakSerdar well that's exactly what I said. All read/write access to the global variable are with the same mutex guard by all threads.

Comment: That's not exactly what you asked in the question. The visibility guarantee is only after mutex is unlocked by the writer, and while it is locked by the reader. Writing to a variable in a mutex guarded code block does not make that write immediately visibile. It makes it visible after the writer unlocks, and reader locks.

Comment: @BurakSerdar All access to the variable will happen with a mutex lock follow by unlock by all threads, both reading and writing. That's what I think the question clearly asks for. But I will edit it to show that even more clearly.